# Rewrite file data using command line Unix utilities

Tags: bash, unix, awk, sed

I have a file like this:

```
 "4" 15356 15422
 "8" 15289 15355
 "7" 14145 15288
 "6" 14071 14139
```

How can I use awk or another bash tool to rewrite this to

```
 mm4 15356 15422
 mm8 15289 15355
 mm7 14145 15288
 mm6 14071 14139
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With sed, assuming the file is `file`:

```
sed 's/"/mm/;s/"//' file
```

Answer (score 2):

With GNU sed:

```
sed -r 's/"([0-9]+)"/mm\1/' file
```

Output:

```
 mm4 15356 15422
 mm8 15289 15355
 mm7 14145 15288
 mm6 14071 14139
```

Answer (score 2):

`sed` would be the simplest and most efficient tool to use. I'd use a regular expression substitution command similar to

```
sed 's/"\([0-9]*\)"/mm\1/' filename
```

This searches for a pattern of digits (zero or more) enclosed within double quotes and substitutes them with the matched digits preceded by `mm`.

While, I only have a copy of GNU sed at hand, the above should work for all versions of sed since it uses only [Basic Regular Expressions as defined by POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_03).

---

If you’re using GNU sed and to want to replace the contents of the file, you
could include the `-i` / `--in-place` flag:

```
sed -i.bak 's/"\([0-9]*\)"/mm\1/' filename
```

This modifies the contents of `filename` after making a backup copy of it as
`filename.bak`. If you don’t want a backup file, omit the suffix from the `-i` option.

Answer (score 2):

another alternative

```
tr -d '"' <file | sed 's/^ / mm/'

 mm4 15356 15422
 mm8 15289 15355
 mm7 14145 15288
 mm6 14071 14139
```

ps. preserves leading space